# Enum binding with DataGridViewComboBoxColumn through interface or not

Tags: c#, sql, datagridview, enums

The way i assign values to an sql column "Service Type" is with the help of an enum:

```
public enum EmployeeType : int
{ 
    CallCenter = 0,
    Secretary = 1,
    Supervisor = 2,
    Director = 3
}
```

Sql db looks like this:
[image: sql table]

And the VS 2013 interface, where i am trying to build the datagridview with a working combo box is here:
[image: VS 2013]

What i can't achieve is that the combobox works correctly. It should show the current value but in a string not in a number. I cannot assign the enum's string value as the DisplayMember.
[image: Result]

So In the end i have a datasource from the db and an enum with the display name. How can i properly show the display name, using the data from the db and enum?

Answer (score 0):

Since i could not figure out a solution i threw away the solution with the enum. Instead of that i transfered the classes to the sql database and there it was easier to configure that with datasets in vs 2013.